# My missing media files don't throw 404 error message

Tags: 404-page, enterprise-1.13

This is what I have got in my `.htaccess` file. But it doesn't throw 404 error for missing media files. **It just shows blank page.**

```
############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
```

My sample url: `/media/unknown.jpg`

I have applied all patches. However, I don't know why I still have got `777` permission to my `media` folder. Any suggestion on this too?

Answer (score 1):

It is due to media .htaccess

In file there is below code comment it

```
RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
```

It will show you 404 for missing file.

Comment: If I comment this out, will it trigger any other security issues?